# Saving binary data into SQL SErver database in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a string with Binarydata that is 64bit. I want to store this data into SQlServer database and the column is varbinary(Max).

When I pass the string I am getting an error saying string cannot be converted into varbinary.

How do I store the binary data into sql server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO t1(col1) VALUES(CONVERT(varbinary(MAX),'text'))
```